# How can you remote boot over InfiniBand?

Tags: networking, iscsi, infiniband

If I have InfiniBand adapters in two computers, an InfiniBand cable between them, and all of my hard drives in one of the computers running the necessary host software (iSCSI/SRP/etc), how would the computer without any hard drives start to remote boot?

I understand iSCSI over an Ethernet card.  The BIOS must have "enough" Ethernet card support/drivers built in to bootstrap the loading.

But, how does the boot sequence start with a non-integrated InfiniBand adapter, on a fairly traditional motherboard like a MSI X99S SLI Plus?  Can it?  Does its BIOS understand enough of InfiniBand to bootstrap?  Of course, since it's not booted, IPoIB can't be used (unless built into the BIOS).

I've read this is possible, and am in the middle of setting it up, and just had a wait, this isn't going to work, I must have misunderstood something moment.  Wondering if I have to have at least one hard drive installed to start the process...